# android getIntent().getSerializableExtra() returns null

Tags: android

I am trying to send bean object(implents `Serializable`) with 16 strings data obtained from a parser. I am sending that using `putExtra("string",serializablevalue)` and I'm receiving that using `getIntent().getSerializable("string")`. I have used this option for almost 10 functionalities it works fine for me.But particular this functionality alone  always returns me null in receiving location.I have cross checked it while sending.it has value. While in the receiving location.

My doubt will bean with 16 fields could be sent with this method. Suggest me a better solution for this problem.

Comment: Show us the code (sender + receiver) in question.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("string")
```

Answer (score 0):

My code works fine with `ArrayList<String>`. Could you please give me/us your serializable-strings?

On the other side, based on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html, then if you use custom class, you need to "transfer" the data between: `public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)` and `private MyParcelable(Parcel in)`.

In details, you can write your data to `out`, and get them from `in`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the String are equals to in both activities!!
it happened to me I had one different capital letter, when I corrected it it worked :)